# Neural Networks parameters are stable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am experimenting audio classification.

My code -

```
x_train = (800, 32, 1)
x_test = (200, 32, 1)
y_train = (800, 1)
y_test = (200, 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=20, padding='same', input_shape=(32,1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=15, padding='same',  activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=96, kernel_size=10, padding='same',  activation="relu"))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(96, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    loss ='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.01),
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)
model.summary()

red_lr= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=1, factor=0.001, mode='min')
check=ModelCheckpoint(filepath=r'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/genre/cnn.hdf5', verbose=1,save_best_only = True)

History = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=30,batch_size=128,validation_data = (x_test, y_test),verbose = 2, callbacks=[check, red_lr,],shuffle=True )
```

I started with 1 layer and increases the layer for accuracy
The best model I had had these values - (loss: 0.5385 - acc: 0.8275 - val_loss: 0.8758 - val_acc: 0.7400)

I run 4 to 5 times all are having the same pattern in val_acc and val_loss
These two parameters are increasing gradually and after half of the epochs are executed it will become stable for the rest of the epochs...Like this,

[image: Accuracy]
[image: Loss]

Any suggestions to increase accuracy and, why the loss is not changing in half of the epochs

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers. You model is already at a local minimum or it is overshooting a local minimum. What you can do to test it is to set a lower learning rate in your optimizer function:

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001) # change it to 0.001 or even lower
```

Comment: I check with most of the optimizer and reduced the learning rate but still, the accuracy is not increased...